# Use Enum as parameter in Named Query

Tags: java, enums, named-query

I have a named query that selects all the record that have a search string in it.

This is my `NamedQuery`.

```
@NamedQuery(
        name = "findAllPersonBySearch",
        query = "SELECT p FROM Person p "
                     + "WHERE LOWER(p.pvId) LIKE LOWER(:searchString) "
                     + "OR LOWER(p.firstName) LIKE LOWER(:searchString) "
                     + "OR LOWER(p.middleName) LIKE LOWER(:searchString) "
                     + "OR LOWER(p.lastName) LIKE LOWER(:searchString) "
                     + "OR p.birthDate LIKE :searchString"
)
```

The record contains 2 enum in it. One is Gender and the Other is Person Type. Here are my enums:

***PersonType***

```
package ph.com.smesoft.hms.reference;

public enum PersonType {
    Customer, Personnel
}
```

***Gender***

```
package ph.com.smesoft.hms.reference;

public enum Gender {
    Male, Female
}
```

I have a search box in my list view which returns a string whenever the Search button is clicked.

How do I use the enums as parameters in my Named Query?

I have tried this:

```
ph.com.smesoft.hms.reference.PersonType.Personnel = :searchString
```

But nothing happened. Hope someone can help me out on this!

**UPDATE:**

This is where the method that accepts the string passed from the Controller and sets it as query parameter:

```
    public List<Person> findAllBySearch(String searchString){
    TypedQuery<Person> searchResult = em.createNamedQuery("findAllPersonBySearch", Person.class);
    searchResult.setParameter("searchString",'%'+searchString+'%');
    List<Person> result=searchResult.getResultList();
    return result;
 }
```

and this is my controller method that accepts the string typed from the view:

**Controller Method**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
public String listofFloor(@ModelAttribute("SearchCriteria") SearchForm searchForm, Model uiModel) {
    uiModel.addAttribute("people", personService.findAllBySearch(searchForm.getSearchString()));
    return "people/list";
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. Your query doesn't have any predicate on gender nor person type. So, what's the problem? You would use an enum like any other parameter: `where p.gender = :gender`, where the type of the passed parameter would be Gender. To get a Gender instance from a STring, you use Gender.valueOf().

Comment: @JBNizet I just removed the enums in my named query but I jave tried this: **ph.com.smesoft.hms.reference.PersonType.Personnel = :searchString** and also p.gender = :searchString. I need to compare it to the query parameter **:searchString**

Comment: You can't compare a field of type Gender with a String. Because those are different types. searchString should be of type Gender. Transform that string to a Gender before passing it as parameter to the query, using Gender.valueOf().

Comment: That condition is just part of a query that has a lot of other conditions in it. If I transform that string to an enum, wouldn't it affect all the other conditions?

Comment: Well, don't transform it for other conditions that need a String parameter. Pass two parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I do that? @JBNizet I updated my code and added the method where I set the query parameter. Hope u can help me out.